# Unable to create popups for features created via KML data

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Using OpenLayers 2.12, I'm retrieving KML map data, containing map point locations from a remote server. The data is successfully received by my Javascript, features are created, and I can see the location markers on my map.

What I try to do then is create a popup when each location is clicked. Here's my 'feature selected' event handler:

```
function site_selected(event) {

    var feature = event.feature;
    feature.closeBox = true;
    feature.popupClass = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud, {
        'autoSize': true
    });
    feature.data.popupContentHTML = '<div>hello</div>';
    feature.data.overflow = "auto";
    feature.lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(feature.geometry.x, feature.geometry.y);
    var popup = feature.createPopup(true);
    popup.show();
}
```

However, the call to `feature.createPopup(true)` returns null.

I've looked at the popup example, but that doesn't involve loading KML data.
I set the lonlat property, however I'm still getting null returned. Question is, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that using the following code creates a popup and displays it on the map:

```
popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("popup",
        new OpenLayers.LonLat(feature.geometry.x,feature.geometry.y),
        new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
        "example popup",
        true);

map.addPopup(popup);
popup.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

look at please "popup" examples https://github.com/ccnmtl/openlayers/tree/master/openlayers/examples

line createPopup function :
https://github.com/ccnmtl/openlayers/blob/master/openlayers/examples/popupMatrix.html#L857

Comment: I've looked at the popupMatrix example. That's where I adapted my code from, but the example isn't using KML data.